# create a geotiff file from undocumented tif image

Tags: gdal, geotiff

I have an undocumented tiff image which I need to use with a software that can read only geotif files. my simplest idea was to pretend the image is at 0N, 0W with a pixel size of 0.00000899928° (1m) in both directions.

I have rea the thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10956818/create-geotiff-from-tiff-and-4-corners-latitude-and-longitude) but I was unable to reproduce the answer. 
Thanks for helping. I am a dummy in geodesics, GIS and the like.

Answer (score 0):

You are attempting to [**georeference**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Georeference) a raster, which is often a difficult task, with multiple techniques. It's not possible to provide an answer for your question given the information you have supplied. Also, never assume that lengths in degrees can be converted to lengths in metres (the Earth isn't flat).

Search around GIS.SE for ideas , e.g. [using the [georeferencing] tag](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/georeferencing). There are tools available with QGIS to help manually georeference rasters to other geospatial data.